# Jquery doesn't load in firefox and internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a website hosted and when I open it on google chrome all work ok, but in firefox and internet explorer javascript doesn't loads.

This is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Me gustas cuando callas | ...es nombre de BLOG</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es" />
    <meta name="description" content="Me gustas cuando callas es un proyecto nacido de la ilusión común de un grupo de personas de distintas edades, sexos y lugares del mundo, personas diferentes  a quienes la casualidad o tal vez el destino reunió en un mismo lugar." />
    <meta name="author" content="gresking@gmail.com" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="me, gusta, cuando, callas" />
    <meta name="robots" content="all" />
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link href="css/ui/jquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="css/img/favicon.ico" />
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/fonts/caviardreams.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>CONTENT</body></html>
```

And I have realised that it must be jquery, cos I include an alert("test"); and it works but all inside $(document).ready(function(){...}); doesn't.

Help PLS! :(

Comment: Check the developer tools, is the file found at all?

Comment: Does jQuery(document).ready(); work? If you are loading jQuery and $() doesn't work, you may have a conflict with another library, and jQuery went into no-conflict mode.

Comment: I dont have other library and the file is founded.

Comment: Give a link to your page and we can give you more information. Also, I suggest using absolute paths, and I suggest using Google's CDN for jQuery.

Comment: [www.megustascuandocallas.com](http://www.megustascuandocallas.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because I used a reserved name "var class"

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities:

**1)**  The code is wrapped in a `document.ready`. Is the page ever completely finished loading?

Perhaps there is a broken image, timing-out api call, or some other resource that is causing the page to not be fully loaded in one browser, while in other browsers it cuts off the calls at a certain amount of time.
**Edit**

I checked the developer console of chrome, and a few images are not loading

`ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_f6f6f6_1x100.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

I bet other browsers are not triggering `ready` because of this.

**2)** Sometimes browsers interpret and fix url problems like the following:

```
/js/jsfile.js
http://www.mysite.com//js/jsfile.js
```

or

```
js/jsfile.js
http://www.mysite.comjs/jsfile.js
```

when those are included as relative link addresses. Perhaps there is a url error and one browser fixes it for you, and the other interprets it correctly?

**3)** Another possibility could be that one of your other js files conflicts with jQuery and jQuery goes into no-conflict mode causing `$()` not to work, but instead using `jQuery()`

Comment: This is the URL and I've tried all you've written :/ [link}http://megustascuandocallas.com/  If you click "crear cuenta" at the top and it opens a modal box jquery loads.

Comment: it was because I used a reserved name "var class"

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the jquery js file if you type this in FF or IE?

```
http://<yoursite_URL>/js/jquery.js
```

Try with this as well:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

You can also try with external jquery library to see if it makes any differences:

This might be a better option unless you have custom code inside jquery :)

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load your page in Firefox (I Googled it) with firebug enabled then you get an error in the file js/plugins.js:

> flashver.split is not a function

I'm not sure what that line of code is doing, but flashVer is set to -1 at the beginning, and I guess it is meant to be set to a string but isn't for some reason.